# Fejer's theorem for Fourier transforms of $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, lp-spaces, fourier-transform, fejer-kernel

I know there is a version of Fejer's theorem stating:"If $f$ is a function in $L^1(\mathbb{(- \pi, \pi)})$ then its Fejer's sums converge to $f$ in $L^1$ norm".

> The question is: is this still true for Fourier transforms? I mean, is it true that 
>   $$\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-N}^{N} \left(1- \frac{|\phi|}{N} \right) \widehat{f(\phi)} e^{ix \phi} d\phi = f(x)$$
>   in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ for $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$?

I know this is true for continuous functions, and that the proof is very similar for both Fejer's sums and for this integral (you still use a convolution).

The problem here is that for the proof above (both for Fourier series and Fourier transform) you evaluate the $f$ at some point and say it is bounded. So how do you do for $L^1$ functions, whose value is not defined in single points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **The answer is yes if $f,\widehat{f} \in L^1(\Bbb R)$**

The following results are well known:

> **Theorem:** 1-$f\in L^1(\Bbb R)$ then $\widehat{f} $ is continuous.

> 2-similarly, $f, \widehat{f} \in L^1(\Bbb R)$ then $f$ is continuous.

> 3- If $f,\widehat{f} \in L^1(\Bbb R)$ Then, $$ \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\Bbb R} \widehat{f(\phi)} e^{ix \phi} d\phi =  f(x)$$

Let $f_N(\phi)=   \left(1- \frac{|\phi|}{N} \right) \widehat{f(\phi)} e^{ix \phi}\mathbf1_{(-N,N)}(\phi) \to \widehat{f(\phi)} e^{ix \phi} $

We have,
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}f_N(\phi)=   \lim_{N\to\infty}\left(1- \frac{|\phi|}{N} \right) \widehat{f(\phi)} e^{ix \phi}\mathbf1_{(-N,N)}(\phi) =\widehat{f(\phi)} e^{ix \phi} $$  pointwise and
$$|f_N(\phi)| =   |\left(1- \frac{|\phi|}{N} \right) \widehat{f(\phi)} e^{ix \phi}\mathbf1_{(-N,N)}(\phi)|\le |\widehat{f(\phi)}| \in L^1(\Bbb R). $$
Then by convergence dominated theorem and the above theorem we have,

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-N}^{N} \left(1- \frac{|\phi|}{N} \right) \widehat{f(\phi)} e^{ix \phi} d\phi \to \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\Bbb R} \widehat{f(\phi)} e^{ix \phi} d\phi =  f(x).$$

> **Counterexample:**
> Now if $\widehat{f} \not\in L^1(\Bbb R)$ then it is not always true take

$$f(x) =\mathbf1_{(-1,1)}(x) $$

then, $$\widehat{f}(\phi) =c\frac{\sin\phi}{\phi}\not\in L^1(\Bbb R)$$

You can check that The property fails here.

Comment: Tyhanks, but in the highlighted rectangle shouldn't you also suppose $f$ continuous in x? Otherwise how can you evaluate $f$ in that point?

Comment: @tommy1996q    of course . if the Fourier transform is integralble then the function is continuous.  as we know that Fourier transforms of àn integralble function is continuous

Comment: Yeah, but this is a bit different. You take $f$ in $L^1$ such that its Fourier transform is in $L^1$ too. Then you define $f(x)$ through the integral, but in general the $f$ you define is a continuous function (let's call that $f_1$ ) such that (for how you have constructed it) the $L^1$ norm of $f-f_1$ is 0 and thus $f$ and $f_1$ are the same function in the $L^1$ space. Am I right?

Comment: @tommy1996q  I see your problem that is a theorem : If a function and it's Fourier transform are integralble then the Fourier transform invertible. this is precisely the result I used there.

Comment: @tommy1996q have a look to the edit. I put all the details

Comment: @GuyFsone Hello sorry to disturb you. But I saw in this post (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754017/fejers-theorem-in-relation-to-the-fourier-transform) it is said that Fejer kernel is a good kernel. Does it mean the Fejer sum actually converges to $f$ in $L^1$? Also, I don't know check how to check that the counterexample you mentioned indeed fails. Can you give a hint?

Comment: @ZhangYuhan Fejer kernel is a good kernel in the sense that it has convolution property (it is a good mollifier for periodic functions) see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fejér_kernel. The counter-example shows that f can be discontinuous if $\hat{f}$ is not integrable.